# XSLT output not as expected

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a requirement to remove parent xml nodes and copy entire xml inside  node. I have written a xslt code it, however, it is not working as expected.

Input XML:

```html
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
  <ns0:Message1>
    <ns3:Response xmlns:ns3="urn:enoc.com:HTRUAE:EmployeeLeavesData_Portal">
      <EmployeeLeave>
        <EmployeeID>100064</EmployeeID>
        <EmployeeAbsenceDays>1</EmployeeAbsenceDays>
      </EmployeeLeave>
      <EmployeeLeave>
        <EmployeeID>100065</EmployeeID>
        <EmployeeAbsenceDays>1</EmployeeAbsenceDays>
      </EmployeeLeave>
    </ns3:Response>
  </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

XSLT mapping:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Response xmlns:ns3="urn:enoc.com:HTRUAE:EmployeeLeavesData_Portal">
      <xsl:copy-of select="Messages/Message1/Response/EmployeeLeave" />
    </Response>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output that I am getting:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response xmlns:ns3="urn:enoc.com:HTRUAE:EmployeeLeavesData_Portal" />
```

expected output:

```html
<ns3:Response xmlns:ns3="urn:enoc.com:HTRUAE:EmployeeLeavesData_Portal">
  <EmployeeLeave>
    <EmployeeID>100064</EmployeeID>
    <EmployeeAbsenceDays>1</EmployeeAbsenceDays>
  </EmployeeLeave>
  <EmployeeLeave>
    <EmployeeID>100065</EmployeeID>
    <EmployeeAbsenceDays>1</EmployeeAbsenceDays>
  </EmployeeLeave>
</ns3:Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2 or 3 you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="//ns3:Response" copy-namespaces="no" xmlns:ns3="urn:enoc.com:HTRUAE:EmployeeLeavesData_Portal"/>
 </xsl:template>
 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Martin,

Thank you for the answer.