# XSLT: Get result elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to extract all `result` elements from my xml:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:cercarIndexCCCICResponseV2 xmlns:ns2="http://salut.gencat.cat/hc3/etccerques" xmlns:ns3="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:ns4="http://principal.agenda.consulta.ws.hc3.salut.cat/">
            <ns2:UpdateResponseDocument>
                <idMissatge>123456</idMissatge>
                <resultCode>OK</resultCode>
                <result>
                    <executionCode>ETC_ICI_000</executionCode>
                    <executionDetails>El procés s'ha dut a terme correctament.</executionDetails>
                </result>
                <result>
                    <executionCode>HC3_CIA_006</executionCode>
                    <executionDetails>No s'ha obtingut informació de la UP: 01785</executionDetails>
                </result>
                ...
                <indexCCCICResponseV2>
                    ...
                </indexCCCICResponseV2>
            </ns2:UpdateResponseDocument>
        </ns2:cercarIndexCCCICResponseV2>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I need to generate it to:

```xml
<responseDocument>
  <results>
    <result>
      <executionCode>ETC_ICI_000</executionCode>
      <executionDetails>...</executionDetails>
    </result>
    <result>
      <executionCode>HC3_CIA_006</executionCode>
      <executionDetails>...</executionDetails>
    </result>
    ...
  </results>
</responseDocument>
```

I've tried this xsl:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <responseDocument>
    <xsl:copy-of select="//resultCode" copy-namespaces="no"/>
    <results>
      <xsl:copy-of select="//result" copy-namespaces="no"/>
    </results>
  </responseDocument>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm only getting `results` elements:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<responseDocument>
   <resultCode>OK</resultCode>
   <results>
      <result>
         <executionCode>ETC_ICI_000</executionCode>
         <executionDetails>El procés s'ha dut a terme correctament.</executionDetails>
      </result>
      <result>
         <executionCode>HC3_CIA_006</executionCode>
         <executionDetails>No s'ha obtingut informació de la UP: 01785</executionDetails>
      </result>
      ...
   </results>
</responseDocument>
```

You can see this template at [here](http://xsltransform.net/6qCcddg/3).

Any ideas?

Comment: You get several useful error messages; why don't you try to follow them?

Comment: You're still way off. See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65823065/3016153.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <responseDocument>
    <results>
      <xsl:copy-of select="//result" copy-namespaces="no"/>
    </results>
  </responseDocument>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I've edited post. I'm struggling with trying to "map" other elements following the same login, but it doesn't work at all. Please, could you take a look [here](http://xsltransform.net/6qCcddg/3)...?

Comment: @Jordi, please don't add new requirements to a question after having received an answer that solved the problem as originally posted.

Comment: Sorry. I restore the original post.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to match root template and then navigate to the element you want to for-each inside `<xsl:for-each select="parent/targetElement">`. Selects inside XSLT like `<xsl:for-each select="">` and `<xsl:value-of select=""/>` work with XPath, so I suggest you check it.

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns2="http://salut.gencat.cat/hc3/etccerques"
exclude-result-prefixes="soap ns2">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <responseDocument>
        <results>
            <xsl:for-each select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns2:cercarIndexCCCICResponseV2/ns2:UpdateResponseDocument/result">
                <result>
                    <executionCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="executionCode"/>
                    </executionCode>
                    <executionDetails>
                        <xsl:value-of select="executionDetails"/>
                    </executionDetails>
                </result>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </results>
    </responseDocument>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: You need to import the namespaces that you are selecting inside xslt.

I've tested the transformation with https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html and I got the following result:

```
<responseDocument>
   <results>
      <result>
         <executionCode>ETC_ICI_000</executionCode>
         <executionDetails>El procés s'ha dut a terme correctament.</executionDetails>
      </result>
      <result>
         <executionCode>HC3_CIA_006</executionCode>
         <executionDetails>No s'ha obtingut informació de la UP: 01785</executionDetails>
      </result>
      <result>
         <executionCode>HC3_CIA_009</executionCode>
         <executionDetails>Error al consultar al servei web de curs clínic per INDEX, al fer la consulta a l'URL: https://hccc-ics.ics.gencat.cat/HCCdes/WSCursClinicIntegrat.asmx de l'Up: 00744</executionDetails>
      </result>
   </results>
</responseDocument>
```